# Self-triggered perpetually running Firebase process using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a set of records that I would like to update sequentially in perpetuity. Basically:

1. Get least recently updated record
2. Update record
3. Set date of record to now (aka. send it to the back of the list)
4. Back to step 1

Here is what I was thinking using Firebase:

```
// update record function
var updateRecord = function() {

    // get least recently updated record
    firebaseOOO.limit(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        key = _.keys(snapshot.val())[0];

        /*
         * do 1-5 seconds of non-Firebase processing here
         */

        snapshot.ref().child(key).transaction(

            // update record
            function(data) {
                return updatedData;
            },

            // update priority after commit (would like to do it in transaction)
            function(error, committed, snap2) {
                snap2.ref().setPriority(snap2.dateUpdated);
            }
        );
    });
};

// listen whenever priority changes (aka. new item needs processing)
firebaseOOO.on('child_moved', function(snapshot) {
    updateRecord();
});

// kick off the whole thing
updateRecord();
```

Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this type of daemon is precisely what was envisioned for use with the Firebase NodeJS client. So, the approach looks good.

However, in the `on()` call it looks like you're dropping the `snapshot` that's being passed in on the floor. This might be application specific to what you're doing, but it would be more efficient to consume that `snapshot` in relation to the `once()` that happens in the `updateRecord()`.

Comment: Vikrum, if I'm understanding you correctly, are you suggesting I pass the snapshot to updateRecord() and ditch the once()? The only reason I use once() is just in case a child moved somewhere in the middle other than the top spot - in which case I still want to process the top spot. Does this sound right or am I off? Another way of putting it is that I don't want to process the moved child, but the resulting top spot after the child moved.

Comment: Got it—your explanation makes sense. Code looks fine in that case! :)